# Filter in Jquery mobile Listview on CountBubble only

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, filter

I have a list of CustomerName with MobileNumber and a Count Bubble which is indicating the Numberofpeople with him/her.

Now I am trying to filer these customer names with the Numberofpeople with him/her.Its working fine. But the main problem is jqueryMobile filtering the list with all the string. If i put 5 for searching its searching in Numberofpeople and Mobilenumber also. But i want that search will be only on NumberOfPeople which is shoiwing in countbubble not with Listview Item. 
I search a lot but did not find the solution. Please help me.[image: Don't need filter on mobile number. Filter will be only on Count bubble.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.. just put the attribute 'data-filtertext' in li.

NoOfPerson will be the value like 5 or 6.

Now JqueryMobile will search the value which is in the data-filtertext. Not in the entire li.